# dynamically adding list item to j-Query Mobile List View

Tags: jquery, html, listview, jquery-mobile

I am trying to populate a list view using j query mobile

My html code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

<title>Demo Page</title>
```

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css"/>

function onDeviceReady() {}
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function Button_onclick() {

for(i=0; i < 3; i++){
        $("#numbers").append('<li>' +i+'</li>' );
}
```

}

```
<div >
    <input id="Click_Button" type="button" value="Submit" onclick="Button_onclick()" />
</div>

<div id="divList" data-role="content">
    <ul id="numbers" data-role="listview" data-inset="true"> </ul>
</div>
```

Expected Result was like this

[image: Result i Expected]

But the result i got was like this

[image: Result Obtained]

Can any one tell me what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you dynamically alter the listview you need to refresh it for JQM to apply the correct styles. You need to do this everytime you add an item (or items) to a list.

This can be achieved with the following statement:

```
$('#numbers').listview('refresh');
```

if you want to read more about this I want to refer you to the JQM doc:
http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/lists/docs-lists.html (Updating lists, at the bottom of the page)

Comment: please mark it as the response then so this question can be closed.

Answer (score 0):

append this `onbuttonclick.`

```
$("#numbers").append('<li style="list-style-position:inside;border: 1px solid black;">'+i+'</li>' );
```

`li style="list-style` will keep `li` text inside and
`border` will create box around `li`

and use this for first and last li item.

```
//for first child
li:last-child{
border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
}
//for last child
li:first-child{
border-top-left-radius: 6px;
border-top-right-radius: 6px;
}
```

Comment: i tried your sugession .actually that not the result that i wanted anyway thanks for your effort and concern